# React forms - unable to set values to null after form submission

Tags: reactjs, forms

[this is the form component that was not resettin or custom changing  after submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gCF0.png)
[this is the item list component (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIuLB.png) ][this is form output after submitting a item (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OChL5.png)]
I really dont seem understand why setformdata works for onchange event but not for the onsubmit event

Answer (score 1):

You should set value of input that named "product" :

```
<input name='product' value={formData.product} ...//rest attributes />
```

And

```
<input name='quality' value={formData.quality} ...//rest attributes />
```

Answer (score 0):

useState is [asynchronous](https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia). A workaround to get the effect you want is by using `useEffect` hook and adding the variable to the dependency array

```
useEffect(()=>{

//some code here

},[formData])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the input field u need to set the value of formData

```js
<input 
type="text"
placeholder = "prduct name"
value= {formData.product}
onChange={handleChange}
/>
```